# Jasmine report error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'xmlresults.xml'

Tags: javascript, automation, jasmine, protractor, jasmine-reporters

I'm trying to implement jasmine report to my framework that work with Protractor so in the conf.js i put this code

```
onComplete: function(){
var browserName;
var capsPromise = browser.getCapabilities();

capsPromise.then(function (caps) {
  browserName = caps.get('firefox');

  var HTMLReport = require('protractor-html-reporter');

  testConfig = {
    reportTitle: 'Test Execution Report',
    outPath: '/test/e2e/reports',
    testBrowser: browserName,
    modifiedSuiteName: false
  };
  new HTMLReport().from('xmlresults.xml', testConfig);
});
},
```

I already install jasmine reporter with this command

```
npm install --save-dev jasmine-reporters@^2.0.0
```

When I execute my script is not failing but when the execution try to generate the report in the terminal is displaying this:

```
E/launcher - ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'xmlresults.xml'
E/launcher - Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'xmlresults.xml'
```

Is anybody has an idea what is happen with this error?

Hope you can help me.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the file cannot be opened at the path you specified because relative to whatever working directory you are in it isn't there.

Change the path to match the relative target location of your XML results file.

Comment: I don't get what you say, can you give me an example of how should be the code?

Comment: "file" the thing you are trying to open (xmlresults.xml) is not located in the "working directory" the file system location from which your application or test is running.  You have to specify the "path" the location on the files system of the file you want to open.  Put it in the `from` argument like `/path/to/xmlresults.xml`.  Also, check to make sure that file is actually there after you've run the test before cleaning the working directory.

Comment: Oh ok, I get what you say but I think `xmlresults.xml` is the file that should be create and should be locate on the `outPath`, well is what I understan of that code, because I search the document `xmlresults.xml` and is not created.

Answer (score 0):

In conf.js, you need to add two functions(onPrepare() and onComplete()). In order to get html report.
In on prepare

```
var jasmineReporters = require('jasmine-reporters');
jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new jasmineReporters.JUnitXmlReporter({
    consolidateAll: true,
    savePath: './',
    filePrefix: 'xmlresults'
}));
```

In onComplete

```
onComplete: function() {
     var browserName, browserVersion;
     var capsPromise = browser.getCapabilities();
 
     capsPromise.then(function (caps) {
        browserName = caps.get('browserName');
        browserVersion = caps.get('version');
        platform = caps.get('platform');
 
        var HTMLReport = require('protractor-html-reporter-2');
 
        testConfig = {
            reportTitle: 'Protractor Test Execution Report',
            outputPath: './',
            outputFilename: 'ProtractorTestReport',
            screenshotPath: './screenshots',
            testBrowser: browserName,
            browserVersion: browserVersion,
            modifiedSuiteName: false,
            screenshotsOnlyOnFailure: true,
            testPlatform: platform
        };
        new HTMLReport().from('xmlresults.xml', testConfig);
    });
 }
```